# Making a follower a Blade and then still use them?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is it possible to make a follower a member of the blades, yet still be able to have them follow you to aid you on your quests?

Comment: I misinterpreted the title as "Making a follower into a sword and then using that sword" and had to try not to burst out laughing at the thought of the Dragonborn swinging Lydia around by the leg like a zweihander. Heck, it's Skyrim, I wouldn't be surprised if there's a mod (or a glitch) that lets you actually do that.

Comment: @F1Krazy  Different game, but that happened during a D&D session. A new player mistakenly picked up a cursed sword that had a mind of its own. The visual is definitely hilarious

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can still use the follower after you've admitted them into the Blades. Simply find them at the temple and speak to them as you would any other follower to bring up the standard options for getting a follower to join you.

Followers you've recruited into the Blades will generally remain at the temple when they're not accompanying you, with few exceptions.

Do note that when you admit a follower into the Blades you lose them as a follower while they are doing the admittance ceremony. However, immediately following that, they should be available to re-recruit.